# Umbraco Public Access - Custom IsLoggedOn functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.6.4 and protecting content using Umbraco's Public Access with member accounts.

This is working fine, but i want to override how Umbraco determines if a user is logged on, returning the page content if authenticated or calling the logon page set in Umbraco if not.

How can i call a custom method to determine if the user has access or not? Possibly being able to call this via `Members.IsLoggedIn()`.

Thanks